# how to execute UseGuard in nestjs microservie

Tags: api, microservices, nestjs

I'm planning to use my authentication part as a microservice so I user nest js TCP transporter but I don't know how to execute passport local strategy in my microservice I used the below code

```
    @MessagePattern('login')
    @UseGuards(LocalAuthGuard)
    localLogin( loginDto: LoginDto) {
        console.log('awa')
        return loginDto
       // return this.authService.localLogin(req.user, loginDto.email);
    }
```

but it doesn't work any idea how can I authorized local strategy in microservice my local strategy looks like below

```
import { Strategy } from 'passport-local';
import { PassportStrategy } from '@nestjs/passport';
import { Injectable, UnauthorizedException } from '@nestjs/common';
import { AuthService } from './auth.service';
import { Request } from 'express';

@Injectable()
export class LocalStrategy extends PassportStrategy(Strategy) {
   
    constructor(private authService: AuthService) {
        super({
            usernameField: 'email',
            passwordField: 'password',
            passReqToCallback: true,
        });
    }

    async validate(
        email: string,
        password: string,
    ): Promise<{ id: string; isVerified: boolean }> {
        try {
            const user = await this.authService.validateLocalUser(email, password);
            if (!user) {
                //throw new UnauthorizedException();
            }
            return { id: user.id,isVerified: user.isVerified };
        } catch (error) {
            console.log('error')
        }
       
    }
}
```

This is the error I got

```
node:71975) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'reply' of null
    at AppExceptionFilter.catch (/Users/imanthaatapattu/apps/beta-identity-service/node_modules/@nestjs/core/exceptions/base-exception-filter.js:26:24)
    at AppExceptionFilter.catch (/Users/imanthaatapattu/apps/beta-identity-service/dist/common/exception-filters/app-exception.filter.js:29:20)
    at RpcExceptionsHandler.invokeCustomFilters (/Users/imanthaatapattu/apps/beta-identity-service/node_modules/@nestjs/microservices/exceptions/rpc-exceptions-handler.js:34:32)
    at RpcExceptionsHandler.handle (/Users/imanthaatapattu/apps/beta-identity-service/node_modules/@nestjs/microservices/exceptions/rpc-exceptions-handler.js:13:36)
    at RpcProxy.handleError (/Users/imanthaatapattu/apps/beta-identity-service/node_modules/@nestjs/microservices/context/rpc-proxy.js:24:34)
    at /Users/imanthaatapattu/apps/beta-identity-service/node_modules/@nestjs/microservices/context/rpc-proxy.js:17:29
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)
(node:71975) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 3)
(node:71975) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

Comment: ' TypeError: Cannot read property 'reply' of null', can you show us the code where you used reply

Comment: @Youba i didn't use reply anywhere

Answer (score 0):

[Passport](http://www.passportjs.org/) is an [Express](https://expressjs.com/) middleware, meant for use over HTTP. You're using it with a middleware, which isn't quite expected. If you want to continue using passport with a microservice, you need to provide the same values it expects under the HTTP context. You can see [Nest's implementation of the `AuthGuard` here](https://github.com/nestjs/passport/blob/master/lib/auth.guard.ts). The most important part of this, is making sure that `getRequest` returns an object with the property `body` and with `body` having the properties `email` and `password`. It would most likely be easier to write your own microservice specific guard that can determine if the request is valid or not (via a JWT or similar)

Comment: sorry I'm new to nestjs what do you mean by creating my own microservice specific guard?

Comment: I mean to create your own guard, that doesn't make use of passport, that does the authentication check. You'll probably need to make use of `context.switchToRpc()` to make sure you get the right information in the guard.